# Emulate aggregate initialization for recursively-defined array-like class

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17, list-initialization

Consider:

```
template <std::size_t r,std::size_t d>
struct Tensor
{
  Tensor<r-1u,d> Data[d];
};

template <std::size_t d>
struct Tensor<0u,d>
{
  double Data;
};
```

We can use copy-list-initialization to initialize such a `Tensor` this way:

```
Tensor<2u,3u> t= { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,
                   4.0, 5.0, 6.0,
                   7.0, 8.0, 9.0 };
```

Note the brace elision.

This also works in a generic programming context, *e.g.*:

```
template <typename... T,
  typename= std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<T,double> && ...) && (sizeof...(T)==9u)>>
Tensor<2u,3u> MakeTensor(T... x) { return {x...}; }
```

However, if `Data` were private, `Tensor` would no longer be an aggregate and thus, the above syntax wouldn't be valid.

In that case, could this behaviour be recovered back programmatically?

Comment: aggregate initialization needs an aggregate, so no, strictly speaking; you can emulate it via an initializer_list constructor though

Comment: ... or a constructor taking an aggregate version of your tensor data structure used only for initialization purposes

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Yes. That might work. Maybe renaming `Tensor` to `TensorData` so that the actual tensor has a private instance of `TensorData` and appropriate constructors. Would you like to elaborate into an answer?

Comment: ok, wait a minute or so :) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate initialization will only work for aggregates, so no, strictly speaking, that's not possible.

You could emulate it either by providing an initializer_list/variadic template constructor or via a constructor taking an aggregate version of your tensor data structure only for initialization purposes, something like:

```
template <std::size_t r,std::size_t d>
struct RawTensor
{
  std::array<RawTensor<r-1u,d>,d> data;
};

template <std::size_t d>
struct RawTensor<0u,d>
{
  double data;
};

template <std::size_t r,std::size_t d>
struct Tensor
{
  Tensor( RawTensor<r,d> const& data ): data_{data}{}

private:
  RawTensor<r,d> data_;
};

template <typename... T,
typename= std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<T,double> && ...) && (sizeof...(T)==9u)>>
RawTensor<2u,3u> MakeTensor(T... x) { return {x...}; }

Tensor<2u,3u> t1 = RawTensor<2u,3u>{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0 };
Tensor<2u,3u> t2 = MakeTensor( 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0 );
```

and letting the compiler optimize it. If your original intent was to exploit chaining of operator[] (and hence you need nested data to be of Tensor type), it's still possible but will require a less trivial initialization logic.